# MS-Word Custom UI Combobox item ID

Tags: xml, vba, combobox, ms-word

I'm attempting to make a combobox on the Ribbon for Microsoft Word (2010). I'm using the Custom UI editor for the XML code, and then using the combobox selection in Word to run macros.

I am very new to this, so this a very basic question. My issue is that inside of Word, I'm having trouble using Select Case to tell which Combobox selection was clicked. I was anticipating that I could do a case based on the item IDs, but that isn't the case (no pun intended). Using the IRibbonControl in the callback, if I try to do a Select Case on control.Id it will only work for the combobox ID.

Here is my XML code:

```
    <comboBox 
        id="Combo1" 
        label="Add Function Switch"
        onChange="OnChange">
                <item id="CB_SC" label="Add SC Switch" />
                <item id="CB_GT" label="Add GT Toggle" />
                <item id="CB_HT" label="Add HT Switch" />
    </comboBox>
```

and my VBA code

```
'Callback for Combo1 onChange
Sub OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String)

Select Case control.id

    Case "CB_SC"
       Do Something
    Case "CB_GT"
       Do Something
    Case "CB_HT"
       Do Something
    Case Else
       Selection.TypeText text:="Selection wasn't registered"

End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done this, but based on your code it looks like your `Select` statement is keyed on the id of the control. I'm assuming you're always getting the `Else` clause.

You need to instead check the `text` value.

Comment: I've tried using the text value, I should have mentioned that above as well...the problem is that select case will still not work off of the item ID. It will work if I do `Select case text `case "Add SC Switch" but hardcoding the text value won't be ideal for some of the things that I have to program in down the line.

Comment: From MSDN "Whenever the value of the combo box is selected, the onChange callback receives the text. However, it is not possible to get the index of the selection." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: It sounds like you need to dynamically control the ribbon. Check out this series of articles on the ribbon in general. The callbacks with the `get` prefix may be of use to you, as they allow the ribbon to be customized on load, or updated based on user events. Hope this helps! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: Excellent, that answers my question about whether it is possible or not. I'll look at both of those links more in-depth. Thanks!